# Regex PHP, remove chars between 2 characters

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove characters between /* and */

I tried with Regex, i think it's very simple, but i'm very bad with this :

---

**Example 1 :**

for this string :

"/*when (aa.kbqeben is null and (aa.KBICBN is null or aa.KBICBN='NOTPROVIDED') then '******TODO******' */else 'ok' end nature_trans,"

I want to keep only : "else 'interbancaire' end nature_trans,"

**Example 2 :**

for this string :

"from prod.TbSepemi /*partition(P_TBSEPEMI_201601) */ aa,"

I want to keep only : "from prod.TbSepemi  aa,"

---

I tried this but it's not working :

```
$string = "/*when (aa.kbqeben is null and (aa.KBICBN is null or aa.KBICBN='NOTPROVIDED') then '******TODO******' */else 'interbancaire' end nature_trans,";
    $string = preg_replace('/\/*[^\]]+\*\//', '', $string);
    echo $string;
```

Comment: The `*` needs to be escaped in every instance, it will be used as a quantifier otherwise. e.g. `\/*` is zero or more forward slashes. Why are you looking for a non `]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/0ajIWW/1)

```
\/\*.*\*\/
```

**Description**

```
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
\* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\* matches the character * literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```